# Incorrect syntax near '@ItemID'

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, sql-update

I am not sure that writing SP with two update statements correct.

I am getting Incorrect syntax near '@ItemID'.
Can you suggestion me ... How can i resolve this.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[ComponentReplaceUSP](@ReplaceItem nvarchar(256) ,@Quantity decimal(28,12) ,@UOM nvarchar(30)) 

AS  
 DECLARE @ItemID INT    
BEGIN       

   Select @ItemID = ItemID  FROM [dbo].[Item] WHERE ItemName =  @ReplaceItem

    UPDATE Item    
      SET Item.ItemName = @ReplaceItem,
      Item.UOM = @UOM
      Where Item.ItemID =@ItemID    


      Update ItemBillOfMaterial
      Set ItemBillOfMaterial.UOM =@UOM,
          ItemBillOfMaterial.Quantity =@Quantity
          Where  ItemBillOfMaterial.CompItem= @ItemID
```

Comment: There is an END missing and you might want to declare the variable after the BEGIN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `CREATE PROCEDURE` query requires an `END`:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[ComponentReplaceUSP](@ReplaceItem nvarchar(256) ,@Quantity decimal(28,12) ,@UOM nvarchar(30)) 
AS   
DECLARE @ItemID INT  
BEGIN           
   Select @ItemID = ItemID  FROM [dbo].[Item] WHERE ItemName =  @ReplaceItem
END
```

Comment: I don't like this answer since the bulk of it is incorrect - there's no need to move the `@ItemID` declaration inside the `BEGIN` block. Unlike some forms of UDF, a stored procedure does *not* need to have its entire body surrounded by a `BEGIN`/`END` pair. And in the TSQL language, it's valid to create a new block (using `BEGIN` and `END`) anywhere that a statement is valid.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Thanks for your comments. I (embarrassingly) didn't realise you could declare the variable outside the `BEGIN`/`END` block. I've amended my answer to only refer to the missing `END` statement.

Answer (score 0):

It should be just a case of moving the declare below the begin as this needs to be declared within the SP.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187926.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It will complain about whatever the last part of the last query is, because you've forgotten to `END` the block you `BEGIN` at line 5.

The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14397224/15498) is wrong with its main assertion that is has anything to do with the `DECLARE` statement. The following is fine:

```
create procedure ABC
as
declare @ID int
begin
    select @ID = object_id from sys.objects
end
```